# MVC treeview click event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, treeview

I am really new to the MVC/jQuery world and having trouble getting the full picture how to set up and handle a treeview click event to pass the full path (Parent & Children) values to a MVC Controller in the treeview below. Example: If I click on Houston. I would like to get the parent path USA,Texas,Houston and then pass to a Controller. If just Texas, then I want USA,Texas. I am using the jstree.com tree view. Thank you for the help.

P.S. In the console log it's say: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

```
<div id="divtree">
            <ul id="tree" >
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Locations</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li onclick="selectNode(event, this);" >
                            <a href="#">Texas</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li onclick="selectNode(event, this);" >
                                    <a href="#">Houston</a>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li onclick="selectNode(event, this);" >
                                            <a href="#">Katy</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                    <ul>
                                        <li onclick="selectNode(event, this);" >
                                            <a href="#">Spring</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>

                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        function selectNode(event, nodeHtmlEl) {
                                            console.log("selectNode Info: " + $(nodeHtmlEl).attr("li").value);
                                        }
                                    </script>
                                </li>
                            </ul>

                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                function selectNode(event, nodeHtmlEl) {
                                    console.log("selectNode Info: " + $(nodeHtmlEl).attr("li").value);
                                }
                            </script>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        function selectNode(event, nodeHtmlEl) {
                            console.log("selectNode Info: " + $(nodeHtmlEl).attr("li").value);
                        }
                    </script>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:

```
<div id="divtree">
    <ul id="tree">
        <li> 
            <a href="#">Locations</a>
            <ul>
                <li> 
                <a href="#">Texas</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li> 
                            <a href="#">Houston</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li> 
                                    <a href="#">Katy</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                            <ul>
                                <li> 
                                    <a href="#">Spring</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#tree a").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var parentEls = $(this).parents('ul').map(function () {
            return $(this).find('a').first().text();
        }).get().join(", ");
        alert(parentEls);
    });
</script>
```

Live example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/sufflavus/QT6YH/6/)

Comment: BTW. In the alert it's comma separated but I don't see the comma in the script. How did you append the commas?

Comment: Browser adds commas in alter(array). I've updated my answer and example. I've added join(", "). Also I think that it's better to use $("**#tree a**").click(...) instead of $("**a**").click(...). In this case you add event listener only for links that in div "tree". It also has been updated.